# BASH FFMPEG SUB HARDCODING;)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I've been working with FFMPEG to hardcode subs.

`$for i in *.mkv;do ffmpeg  -i "$i" -map 1 -filter_complex subtitles=video.ssa -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -copy_unknown -map_metadata:s:v 0:g "../../A/bra/ca/da/bra/SS/taging/C24/${i%.mkv*}.mp4";done`

Below are the error messages I've been receiving since enabling the libass library; however I don't know enough about video editing to understand all of it. My question is in regards to the coding.

In the ffmpeg documentation the AVOption:subtitle_filter_complex section states that the coding should say: `-vf subtitles=video.srt` –– this is their example for the subtitles section –– and they specify that this will take the input subtitle stream and "burn" it onto the video stream of the output.

#### error code ffmpeg

```
$s[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe77ef00000] Unable to open video.ssa
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fe77ee0cf80] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'video.ssa'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory
```

#### complete error message:

```
$[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe77ef00000] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.7.5 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fe77ef00000] Unable to open video.ssa
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fe77ee0cf80] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'video.ssa'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory`
```

My question is how do you utilize the filter_complex in relation to it's example?

The "video.ssa" part of the command revers to the filename of the video which contains the stream.

But does that mean I have to replace the "filename" or "video" with a batch variable?